# Recaptcha v3 protection for Get request

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Came from recaptcha v2 background with my own bot detection logic. I want to try out the new bot detection score feature of v3.

I want to protect my search page from being abused by bots trying to query the DB every 0.5 second.

Search result page accepts url query parameter to allow users to book mark the page. For example `mydomain.com/findallcities?country=xxx&province=yyy&populationmin=5000`

Based on my understanding v3 flow works like this

1. Client calls recaptcha JS function and get a token
2. Client append the token some where in the form so that server can validate the token later
3. Form submit and server receives the token
4. If server gets no token then reject. otherwise validate the token to get user score and act accordingly

So the question comes. How can I tell if its a bot that is hitting `mydomain.com/findallcities?country=xxx&province=yyy&populationmin=5000` with a Get request or if its a legitimate user clicking on a bookmark? There is no token to verify and even if there is its probably an expired (used) one from before.